# Microsoft addins, get properties from manifesto dynamic settings

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, add-in

I'm developing an [Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator/) and I need to store a base URL that will be called to perform an action. I need that this URL can be configurable.

My idea was to save that URL in the manifest.xml but I can't find a way for the adding to get it. I can't find anything related in the Office object (Office.js).

Example:

```
 <bt:Urls>
    <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
    <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
    <bt:Url id="Base.Url" DefaultValue="https://my-base.net/" /> <---- this
  </bt:Urls>
```

Maybe this is not the right way...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the default URL in the add-in manifest and save the new data in the local storage of your add-in. See [Persisting add-in state and settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings) for more information.

But there is no trivial way at present for an Office Add-in to read its own manifest. However, you can load it in JS if you know the exact place where it will be hosted. It is just a file on the web server.

So, I'd suggest avoiding the manifest file for data settings nowadays. It acts like your add-in's metadata. Instead, keep the strings hardcoded in the add-in and store in the settings or local storage the new value.